# help with linq to sql

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Help me with this algorithm please.

```
 var companies = companyrepository.GetAll().OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
string where = "";

if (op == "eq")
  where = field + "=" + data;
else if (op == "cn")
  where = field + " LIKE '%"+data+"%'"; ///here lies my problem

companies = companies.Where(where);
```

its for adding dynamic where clauses to a linq query... op, field, and data are all strings that come with ajax from a jquery grid.

The problem is that it gives me an error when it tries to do the Like operator... it works just fine with the equals operator.

Comment: What seems to be your issue? Are you already using DynamicLinq?  Are the results wrong?

Comment: yes, i am using dynamic linq... it works fine for equals operator but not with Like operator.

Comment: Does it give you an "UnknownErrorException"? If not, then could you post the complete exception it gets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/450880f4-c830-4cc3-8932-2e6c91f1997b), the following should work for you:

```
if (op == "eq")
  where = field + "=" + data;
else if (op == "cn")
  where = field + ".Contains(\"" + data + "\")";
```

I ran some tests on my own data, and it appears to work fine.